# Does "stacking" of thinner timing pulley and belts reduce "belt stretch", as using a wider belt would?

Tags: pulleys, power-transmission

When wanting precise belt driven motion, it is desirable to reduce belt stretch by using a wider and/or stronger belt.  Wider GT family can be quite expensive (hundreds of dollars) compared to thinner belts used for 3d printers.  In certain cases it might be more economical if thinner belts could be "stacked".

Provided that the "stacked" timing belts (not sure if that is the correct term, might also say "in parallel") are coupled to the same shaft and under equal tension, can I expect to benefit from a reduction in belt stretch (without reducing the stretch in my wallet)?

[image]

Comment: More belts means disparity of tension between belts too.  One might stretch more than another making getting the right distribution more difficult.

Comment: The way to get to a narrower belt is to use bigger sprockets. If possible, size the sprockets to land on a particular belt's rated horsepower after all the correction factors are applied. Ganging these belts is a bad idea. Old vee belts can be ganged because they do stretch. And they are sold in matched sets at a premium. Gates specifies that the belt width should not be more than the small sprocket pitch diameter.

Comment: The cost per mile of a belt even 100 or 500 bucks is peanuts when they do 100000 miles...